# Parsing HTML in fragment with jsoup

Tags: android, html, android-fragments, textview, jsoup

I am making an Android app for my website. I know basics of making Android app and I am using Android Developer tool. I had came across a problem which not letting me display data which is fetched from the website.

I tried this code in other project and it works fine. But when I wants to use it with Fragment then don't display anything.

```
    class Description extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String desc;
    String url="http://www.techmuzz.com";   
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            desc = document.title();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        if(desc!=null){
        txtdesc.setText("Description is Null");
        }
        else
        {
            txtdesc.setText("Description has some data.");
        }

    }
}
```

I have this logcat results.

```
09-28 13:26:51.891: D/AbsListView(30083): onDetachedFromWindow
09-28 13:26:56.531: W/dalvikvm(30083): No implementation found for native Ldalvik/system/VMRuntime;.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
09-28 13:26:56.531: E/ActivityThread(30083): Pause GC
09-28 13:26:56.531: E/ActivityThread(30083): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-28 13:26:56.531: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 13:26:56.531: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-28 13:26:56.531: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.pauseGC(ActivityThread.java:5525)
09-28 13:26:56.531: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
09-28 13:26:56.531: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
09-28 13:26:56.531: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
09-28 13:26:56.531: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
09-28 13:26:56.531: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-28 13:26:56.531: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
09-28 13:26:56.531: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
09-28 13:26:56.531: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 13:26:56.531: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-28 13:26:56.531: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
09-28 13:26:56.531: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
09-28 13:26:56.531: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-28 13:26:56.531: E/ActivityThread(30083): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
09-28 13:26:56.531: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc(Native Method)
09-28 13:26:56.531: E/ActivityThread(30083):    ... 15 more
09-28 13:26:56.671: D/ProgressBar(30083): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
09-28 13:26:56.671: D/ProgressBar(30083): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
09-28 13:26:56.671: D/ProgressBar(30083): updateDrawableBounds: right = 96
09-28 13:26:56.671: D/ProgressBar(30083): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 96
09-28 13:26:59.861: W/dalvikvm(30083): No implementation found for native Ldalvik/system/VMRuntime;.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
09-28 13:26:59.861: E/ActivityThread(30083): Pause GC
09-28 13:26:59.861: E/ActivityThread(30083): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-28 13:26:59.861: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 13:26:59.861: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-28 13:26:59.861: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.pauseGC(ActivityThread.java:5525)
09-28 13:26:59.861: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
09-28 13:26:59.861: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
09-28 13:26:59.861: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
09-28 13:26:59.861: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
09-28 13:26:59.861: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-28 13:26:59.861: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
09-28 13:26:59.861: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
09-28 13:26:59.861: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 13:26:59.861: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-28 13:26:59.861: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
09-28 13:26:59.861: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
09-28 13:26:59.861: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-28 13:26:59.861: E/ActivityThread(30083): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
09-28 13:26:59.861: E/ActivityThread(30083):    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc(Native Method)
09-28 13:26:59.861: E/ActivityThread(30083):    ... 15 more
09-28 13:26:59.891: D/AbsListView(30083): Get MotionRecognitionManager
09-28 13:27:02.911: D/dalvikvm(30083): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 378K, 13% free 10265K/11732K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
09-28 13:27:05.336: D/dalvikvm(30083): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 200K, 14% free 10321K/11996K, paused 43ms, total 44ms
09-28 13:27:05.336: I/dalvikvm-heap(30083): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.457MB for 334384-byte allocation
09-28 13:27:05.361: D/dalvikvm(30083): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 128K, 15% free 10520K/12324K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
09-28 13:27:05.386: D/dalvikvm(30083): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 469K, 18% free 10324K/12488K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
09-28 13:27:05.401: D/dalvikvm(30083): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 218K, 17% free 10432K/12488K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
09-28 13:27:05.401: I/dalvikvm-heap(30083): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.671MB for 445840-byte allocation
09-28 13:27:05.416: D/dalvikvm(30083): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 16% free 10867K/12924K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
09-28 13:27:05.431: D/dalvikvm(30083): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 435K, 18% free 10650K/12924K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
09-28 13:27:05.551: D/dalvikvm(30083): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 733K, 16% free 10933K/12924K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
09-28 13:27:05.641: D/dalvikvm(30083): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 514K, 13% free 11532K/13132K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
09-28 13:27:05.821: D/dalvikvm(30083): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 916K, 15% free 11923K/13928K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
09-28 13:27:05.946: D/dalvikvm(30083): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 970K, 15% free 12338K/14412K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
```

Comment: Did you declare the Internet permission in your manifest? If so, do you have a something in your logcat?

Comment: Yes I had declared Internet Permission in Manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `protected void onPostExecute(Void result)` but that does not match `AsyncTask<String, String, String>`. Change to `protected void onPostExecute(String result)`.

And adapt the logic in onPostExecute. Reverse it. As you are now telling that you have data for desc==null;

Your LogCat though has nothing to do with this problem.